Api Google Drive V3 - Eliminar archivos según condición
Utilizando la api v3 de Google, como puedo mantener los últimos 10 archivos e ir eliminando el más antiguo que contengan el nombre "Backup". Misma técnica que utilizan los DVR con las grabaciones.
Todo esto, utilizando VB.NET 2019.
Gracias de ante mano

Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.
